# difference between Kruskal-Wallis and Wilcoxon tests in R

Tags: r

for two datasets (short and long) we carried out NON-parametric hypothesis tests.

- The first one is  Wilcoxon gives p-value = 1.824e-06 < 0.025 and we do reject Ho;
- The second one is Kruskal-Wallis gives p-value = 0.4651 > 0.025 and we do NOT reject Ho.

I have different p-values. Why? What did I do wrong?

```
> wilcox.test(unique(short), unique(long), paired=TRUE) 
data:  unique(short) and unique(long)
V = 0, p-value = 1.824e-06
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

> kruskal.test(unique(short),unique(long), paired=TRUE)
Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
data:  unique(short) and unique(long)
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 29, df = 29, p-value = 0.4651
```

PS.

```
> ks.test(unique(short),"plnorm")
One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
data:  unique(short)
D = 0.22942, p-value = 0.07181
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> ks.test(unique(long),"plnorm")
One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
data:  unique(long)
D = 0.56416, p-value = 1.539e-09
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Answer (score 0):

`kruskal.test` expects the first argument to be the vector of values and the second argument to  be the factor or grouping names for each value.  Given your two vectors you could provide the values to this function as a list like this:

`kruskal.test(list(unique(short),unique(long)))`

that should work, though I'm confused why you're using `unique` but that's is not related to why you're getting different results.

Comment: I tried to analyze my data in the wrong way,
According to 
http://www.biostathandbook.com/kruskalwallis.html
"Use the Kruskal–Wallis test when you have one nominal variable, and one ranked variable."
In my case I have one group of subjects, it is physical exercise execution time, that is lognorm distributed for first condition (p = 0.07) 
 and non-norm distributed for second condition (p = 1.5e-09).

To establish a non-parametric statistical hypothesis test, I suppose that  as wilcox.test must be applied in my particular case (lognormal and non-normal distributions).
Isn't it?